# multidimensional images raw data format

Tags: math

Is there a lowest common denominator format for multidimensional images or matrices analogous to netpbm/netpgm for 2d images?

How would you use protocol buffers to define a 3d image or matrix of 16 bit unsigned numbers?

Why didn't the netpbm people allow more dimensions in the row, column line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [FITS](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/) and [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) fit into that role.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easiest to just have the first line declare the data structure followed by the binary data. 
 For ex. 
 
char * \n
Hello World!

unsigned char [2][2][2]\n
0000000000